# CentOS Apache(httpd) deploying of flask occurs 503 error

Tags: python, flask, devops

I faced 503 error while deploying my flask app on godaddy centos vm, port is 5002 for flask app.

And httpd config in etc/httpd/conf.d/default-site.conf is following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    servername  domain.com
    serveralias domain.com
    serveralias domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5002/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5002/
</VirtualHost>
```

but I am getting the 503 error - "503 Service Unavailable"

Please help me. Thanks in advance

firewall and port status

sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
ports: 100/tcp 2022/tcp 8080/tcp 5000/tcp 3036/tcp 443/tcp 80/tcp 5002/tcp

netstate -l

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:down            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:commplex-main 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:down               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:mysql              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 localhost:323           0.0.0.0
```

Comment: can you check that your flask app is running at port 5002 within the VM?

Comment: app is running at port 5002